# document.cookie expires not working properly in Safari

Tags: javascript, cookies, safari

I have a script where I save login information (email/encrypted pwd) in cookies for about 10 years. It is working in Firefox but, in Safari (on MacOS) it is only saved for a few days.

Here is the code I am using:

```
function setCookie(name, value, days)
{
    if (days)
    {
        var expires = new Date();
        expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
    }
    document.cookie = name + '=' + escape(value) + '; path=/' + ((expires == null) ? '' : '; expires=' + expires.toGMTString());
}

function saveLoginCookies()
{ 
    var keepEmail = $('#keepemail')[0];
    if (keepEmail.checked)
        setCookie('email', $('#email').val(), 3650);
    else
        delCookie('email');
    var keepPwd = $('#keeppwd')[0];
    if (keepPwd.checked)
    {
        setCookie('email', $('#email').val(), 3650); // to make sure we have both the email and pwd even if keepemail is not checked
        setCookie('encpwd', $("#encpwd").val(), 3650);
    }
    else
        delCookie('encpwd');
}
```

Here are the cookies in Firefox:
[Cookies Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnF6V.jpg)
and in Safari
[Cookies Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJigj.jpg)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Jean

Comment: change to localStorage...

Comment: The server needs that data so I cannot use local storage (I think).

Comment: I don't think this way of coding is acceptable today. direct access from a server has become a kind of backdoor for all users' cookies, for each advertising iFrame on a page, I imagine that Apple's policy is tough on this issue, and they are right. Use localStorage and add Ajax if you really need to retrieve user information from a server, this is also a GDPR issue, and it's up to users to choose whether or not to use the password manager that each browser [or system] offer.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but came across it by trying to find an answer myself. Safari has some pretty weird tracking prevention which sets the max cookie expiration date to 7 days, so no matter what you put it will be set to 7 days after the cookie is created.